# Is using a wire rated the same as its circuit's fuse OK?

Tags: automotive, fuses, maximum-ratings

I want to add a kill switch on the fuel pump relay in my car, which includes extending a line connected to a 15A fuse.

I bought some 15A auto wire, but on reflection I'm not 100% sure if that's right. Since the wire is rated the same as the fuse, is there a chance it will melt instead of/at the same time as the fuse in the event of an overload, or am I overthinking it?

Comment: If the wire is rated to safely carry 15 Amp, it will carry a much higher current before melting.  It can safely be protected by a 15 Amp fuse.

Comment: Thanks, @Peter can you please add that as an answer?

Comment: You should also consider the load. If the maximum current it can handle is lower than the wire then you should fuse for it rather than the wiring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the wire is rated to safely carry 15 Amp, it will be able to carry a much higher current before melting. It can safely be protected by a 15 Amp fuse.